# How to run Front End and Backend together in React.js and Express.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have written a program with **React** and **Express** to run in development mode with servers separately, is it possible to run **simultaneously**, and my other question is how it is possible in build mode

Thankful

Comment: There's a package called concurrently that does what you described. https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Adrian mentioned in the comment, you can use [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently)

But require a certain folder structure, in order to run server and client simultaneously

You can try this structure:
[image]

In the package.json file, edit the script:

```
  "scripts": {
    "server": "npm run dev --prefix server",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
```

And, `npm run dev` you can start both at the same time.

Comment: `npm install concurrently` first